# WinRT XAML Toolkit treeview exapander button functionality to heading items

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, winrt-xaml, winrt-xaml-toolkit

I'am developing a windows store application, I have used WinRT XAML Toolkit tree view control for display hierarchical data.
Tree view is populate and working correctly. But I need to do small change, in the treeview it has expander button. I need that functionality into heading item. When user click on heading it should work like expander button. I want to expand the node if user click that heading also. How can i do this? Thanks

Comment: Do you mean you want the tree node to expand when the text gets clicked instead of only when the toggle on the side does?

Answer (score 2):

You can put a `Button` or `ToggleButton` as an item or in `ItemTemplate` (depending on whether you are using `ItemsSource` to populate the `TreeView` with nodes) and handle a `Click` event on the `Button` to toggle the node's expansion state.

Comment: Can you give some example code to handle node's expansion state. I have searched that in the WinRT XAML Toolkit source code. But i couldn't find that. Thanks Filip.